# Presenting a Custom UIViewController without a NIB ? iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a view based application. I am trying to load a second custom view controller when the app starts. I have the following code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
controller = [NewController alloc];  

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];

[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

The problem is that the new view controller is not loading and viewDidLoad is not called. I have no xib file for the second view controller.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Try deleting the app from the device and run it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods. Use `viewDidAppear` instead.

Comment: Thanks. What also seemed to work was adding the view to the current view : [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a call to `init` your view controller...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    controller = [[NewController alloc] init];  

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```